# android listview row number remove zero

Tags: android, listview, numbers, row

I have List view to display title, i need to add row numbers in my getView. My code working fine but my list view Poisson Start from Zero (0), How can i disable it?

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View rowView;
        if(convertView == null) {
            rowView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.searchitemview, null);
        } else {
            rowView = convertView;
        }

        TextView firstTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        firstTextView.setText(items.get(position).first);   

        TextView number = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number);
        number.setText(""+position);

        TextView thirdTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtSize);
        if(items.get(position).fourth != "00:00" || items.get(position).fourth != ""){
            thirdTextView.setText("Duration: " + items.get(position).fourth);
        }else{
            thirdTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

This code start row number from Zero (0) i want my list view row number start from one (1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indexes start from 0 by default, increase it yourself:

```
number.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
```